# Using isset on !$myvar['var']

Tags: php, isset

I'm currently working through a large number of warnings I have logged after my server was updated to PHP 8.

One particular point that has me scratching my head is the following code block

```
if (!$option['type'] || $option['type'] == "select") {
  $output .= '<b>'.$option['title'].':</b>';
}
```

I know that I can use isset($option['type']) like this

```
isset($option['type']) && $option['type'] == "select"
```

but confused how that would work for

```
!$option['type']
```

How can you be checking if isset, but also it being NOT. If it's NOT, then surely it isn't set anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for "[may not exist or may be falsey](https://php.net/empty)" is:

```
if (empty($option['type']))
```